# GIT push fails with remote: Repository not found

Tags: git, github

When I push files from the local to the remote I am gettting the error, "**fatal: repository '' not found**".  Ths is occuring from both the TortoiseGit->Push and the Power shell command line.  The Tortoise push gives same error but then adds, "**git did not exit cleanly (exit code 128)**"  All other commands appear to be working (cloning from remote, adding files and commiting).  I have fellow coworkers where this is working as expected, and my permissions on GITHub appear to be the same.  I have looked on other Stack Overflow questions and cannot find one that helps.

Comment: Does `git remote -v` show the correct URL's for push and fetch? Also, what specifically are you using to push? `git push origin <branch>`? (It's silly, but something like mistyping "origin" will give you that error.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Git remotes *generally* have one location to fetch (used by pull and clone) and push, but they can be different. Since you can clone (fetch), but not push, it's possible these have diverged somehow.

You can check with `git remote -v`. You should see something like this.

```
$ git remote -v
origin  git@github.com:rails/rails.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:rails/rails.git (push)
```

Here I'm using an example of the Github Rails repository. Both fetch and push are the same. If they're different that's likely your problem.

This could be because you have `remote.pushDefault` or other `remote.*` configuration values set. Other possibilities are a broken `http.proxy`. `git config --list --show-origin` will show you all your config settings and where they come from. Look for anything fishy.

Another possibility is that you have permission to fetch, but not push, and your Git server is communicating a permissions problem incorrectly. Though as this is Github I doubt it.

---

> All other commands appear to be working (cloning from remote, adding files and committing)

Side note: Most operations in Git are happening entirely on your local machine. The only relevant commands are `git clone`, `git fetch`, `git push`, and `git pull`. Commit, add, diff, log, rm, etc... are happening locally.

Comment: origin  https://github.wellsfargo.com/<app>/<app>.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.wellsfargo.com/<app>/<app>.git (push)

Comment: The other command that you provided all work (clone, pull & fetch).  Only pull is not working.  I am still looking at the config settings that you mentioned.  Thank you for your help so far

Comment: Concenring those config settings.  I had a team materun the same command.  The only differencwes was that I had an extras setting,file:C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/etc/gitconfig credential.helper=manager, file:H://.gitconfig     credential.helper=manager.  The second one is a remote drive that my teammate did not have.